# Update array data used to create UITableView when IBAction is fired

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

I have created a UITableView that includes a UIImage, and two UILabels. This data is passed to a details view controller when the user selects the row. I have also successfully created a UIButton in the prototype cell that updates the text of one of the UILabels. I am unsuccessfully attempting to update this label within the array so this change is reflected on the details view controller. This is what I tried with no success:

```
@IBAction func updateTableData(_ sender: Any) {
    grinds.removeAll()
    grinds = createArray()
}
```

Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/andrewTuzson/tableViewPractice

In the screenshot below, the left image displays the tableview after the first cell has been toggled to "Needs Work". The right image displays the details screen that is loaded after selecting the row.

[image]

How should I approach solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a tableViewCell upon the button click then, you should make the model array global to access it in click method and update what you want then reload the tableView either with delegate or NSNotificationCenter

--

in the custom class of the cell declare an integer property and in cellForRow set it like this

```
 cell.index = indexpath.row
```

Comment: How would I target that object’s item within the array of objects? When I try using indexPath.row, Xcode yells at me.